# Undefined is not a function (near '...item.map...')-React Native search bar

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am having this error " Undefined is not a function (near '...item.map...') .
I have a data named recipes, what I wanted to do is to filter through the data and have it displayed when searched. the error happens when I enter text in the search box.
I tried to fix it for a while and i am not able to fix it. please help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { FlatList, ImageBackground } from "react-native";
import { SearchBar, Card } from "react-native-elements";
import { RECIPES } from "../shared/recipe";
import Header from "./Header";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes: RECIPES,
      fontsLoaded: false,
      search: [],
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Home",
  };

 
  updateSearch = (recipe) => {
    this.setState({
     
      search: this.state.recipes.filter((rec) =>
        rec.name.toLowerCase().includes(recipe.toLowerCase())
      ),
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    const renderRecipeItem = ({ item }) => {
      if (item) {
        item.map((recipe) =>
          recipe.recipes.map((rec) => {
            return (
              <View
                key={recipe.title + recipe.author + recipe.prepTime}
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 8,
                  margin: 10,
                  padding: 20,

                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  shadowOffset: {
                    width: 1,
                    height: 2,
                  },
                  shadowColor: "grey",
                  shadowOpacity: 0.8,
                  elevation: 2,
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    position: "relative",
                    borderTopStartRadius: 8,
                    borderTopEndRadius: 8,
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      minWidth: "100%",
                      height: 200,
                    }}
                    source={{ uri: rec.image }}
                  />
                  <View style={styles.overlay}></View>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: "40%",
                      color: "rgb(255,250,160)",

                      fontFamily: "RobotoMono-Light",

                      fontSize: 28,
                    }}
                  >
                    {rec.country}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    backgroundColor: "#BF360C",
                    padding: 10,
                    marginTop: 20,
                    borderRadius: 8,
                    opacity: 0.7,
                    width: "100%",
                  }}
                  onPress={() => navigate("FoodInfo", { recipeId: item.id })}
                >
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>RECIPES</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          })
        );
      }
      return <View />;
    };

    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView style={{}}>
          <Header />
          <SearchBar
            round
            lightTheme
            style={{ borderRadius: 5 }}
            placeholder="Search a recipe..."
            onChangeText={(recipe) => this.updateSearch(recipe)}
          />

          <FlatList
            data={this.state.search}
            renderItem={renderRecipeItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    opacity: 0.3,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

this is the recipes data-

```
export const RECIPES = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "thai",
    country: "Thai Cuisine",
    recipes: [
      {
        recipeTitle: "Pad Thai",
        author: "Helen Ma",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568146244603-ea84f076d043?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDl8fHRoYWklMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious  Thai food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
      {
        recipeTitle: "Sushi",
        author: "Laura Chan",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568146244603-ea84f076d043?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDl8fHRoYWklMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious  Thai food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 1,
    name: "taiwanese ",
    country: "Taiwanese Cuisine",
    recipes: [
      {
        recipeTitle: "Noodles",
        author: "Audrey Wang",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613276016849-469ca6b326bd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8Zm9vZCUyMHRoYWl8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious Taiwanese food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
      {
        recipeTitle: "Beef Noodle Soup",
        author: "Jesse Lin",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613276016849-469ca6b326bd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8Zm9vZCUyMHRoYWl8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious Taiwanese food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "american",
    country: "American Cuisine",
    recipes: [
      {
        recipeTitle: "Burger",
        author: "James Burger",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602030638412-bb8dcc0bc8b0?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8YW1lcmljYW4lMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious American food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
      {
        recipeTitle: "Stake",
        author: "James Burger",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602030638412-bb8dcc0bc8b0?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8YW1lcmljYW4lMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious American food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    name: "ethiopian",
    country: "Ethiopian Cuisine",
    recipes: [
      {
        recipeTitle: "Misir Wat (Ethiopian Spiced Red Lentils)",
        country: "Ethiopian Cuisine",
        author: "Sara Thomas",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",

        image:
          "https://food.fnr.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2016/9/7/0/DV2507H_Misir-Wot-Spicy-Red-Lentils_s4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.826.620.suffix/1473350482641.jpeg",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious Ethiopian food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
      {
        recipeTitle: "Doro Wot",
        author: "Girum Elias",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602030638412-bb8dcc0bc8b0?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8YW1lcmljYW4lMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "A very delicious American food that you will enjoy",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Indian",
    country: "Indian Cuisine",
    recipe: [
      {
        recipeTitle: "Chicken Tikka Masala",
        country: "Indian Cuisine",
        author: "Sunita Khan",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr 5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542367592-8849eb950fd8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fGluZGlhbiUyMGZvb2R8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "Authentic Indian recipes",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
      {
        recipeTitle: "Tandoori Chicken",
        country: "Indian Cuisine",
        author: "Sunita Khan",
        rating: 5,
        prep: "10 mins",
        cook: "55 mins",
        total: "1 hr5 mins",
        image:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542367592-8849eb950fd8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fGluZGlhbiUyMGZvb2R8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1DlijLo_I",
        description: "Authentic Indian recipes",
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]; And this is not a _minimal_ example.

Comment: Thank you for Your help @3limin4t0r. I changed the item with data={this.state.search.recipes} . now it does not give me an error, but doesn't render anything when I search.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with React Native, but looking at the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem) it looks like `renderItem` needs to be passed a component that renders each individual item.

An example of such an item is:

```
{
  id: 0,
  name: "thai",
  country: "Thai Cuisine",
  recipes: [ ... ],
}
```

Meaning that `item.map` would result in `undefined` because `item` is not an array, but your "category". You'll have to navigate to the `recipes` property, which returns an array on which you can call `map`. eg. `item.recipes.map(...)`.

You should also remove the nested `map` call `recipe.recipes.map`.

Other issues are mainly naming issues.

1. `recipe.title` does not exist. There is a property `recipeTitle`, but not `title`.
2. `recipe.prepTime` does not exist. There is a property `prep`, but not `prepTime`.
3. `rec.image` should be `recipe.image`.
4. `rec.country` does not exist. And is only available on the "category" (`item`).

The large `style` properties are relevant for the answer, so I've omitted them in the example below to make things better understandable.

```
const renderRecipeItem = ({ item }) => (
  item.recipes.map((recipe) => (
    <View
      key={recipe.recipeTitle + recipe.author + recipe.prep}
      style={{...}}
    >
      <View style={{...}}>
        <Image style={{...}} source={{ uri: recipe.image }} />
        <View style={styles.overlay}></View>
        <Text style={{...}}>
          {item.country}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{...}}
        onPress={() => navigate("FoodInfo", { recipeId: item.id })}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>RECIPES</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  ))
);

// ...

<FlatList
  data={this.state.search}
  renderItem={renderRecipeItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
/>
```